# Link between linear regression and correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares

I happen to do a lot of linear regression,  the typical use case is predicting $Y$ with a few predictors say $X = [X_1;X_2;X_3]$.
So we we find $\hat{\beta}$ such that $$\hat{\beta} = \underset{\beta}{argmin} ||Y-X.\beta||^2$$ But actually what I am more interested in in finding the linear estimation of $Y$ such that $$corr(Y,\hat{Y}) = corr(Y,X.\hat{\beta})$$ is maximal.

I am bothered by the fact that for a given $\beta_0$, $corr(Y,X.a.\beta_0)$ is the same for all $a$, questions are then

Is the optimal linear estimator of $\beta$ in the least square sense also optimal in my correlation term, and if yes should I be bothered that the optimal $\beta$ is not unique ?

Answer (score 3):

Think about $R^2$ of linear regression:

$R^2=1-\frac{\|Y-X\hat\beta_{OLS}\|^2}{\|Y-\bar Y\|^2}=[Corr(Y,X\hat\beta_{OLS})]^2$

Since denominator does not depend on $\hat\beta$ and LS minimizes the numerator the "result follows".

---

You correctly mentioned that the correlation coefficient is invariant under linear transformations (which preserve sign). It means that you cannot use correlation to recover the underlying parameters.

Consider the next univariate model:

$Y_i=X_i\beta+u_i$

For any $b\not=0, |Corr(Y_i. X_ib)|=|Corr(Y_i, X_i)|$

So, it meaningless to maximize sample covariance w.r.t to $b$.

On the other hand, $R^2(b)\le Corr(Y_i, X_ib)^2$ with equality for $b=b_{OLS}$.  In this sense LS yields the optimal estimator.

Comment: good that's what I thought, did not know the correl formula. Any thought about the second question (should I be bothered that an infinite number of $\beta$ maximize the correl) ?